# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'username'")

Tags: python, django

I have the following custom user model implementation in my Django application :

users/models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email: str,
                     password: str, is_staff: bool,
                     is_superuser: bool, **extra_fields):
        """Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email: str, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email: str, password: str, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser, UUIDModel):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'
        ordering = ('-date_joined', )

    def get_full_name(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_email(self):
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.email)
```

And my change form in admin.py looks like this :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as AuthUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm as DjangoUserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm as DjangoUserCreationForm

from .models import User


# Forms
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class MyUserCreationForm(DjangoUserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email",)


class MyUserChangeForm(DjangoUserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'


# ModelAdmins
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(AuthUserAdmin):
    add_form_template = 'admin/auth/user/add_form.html'
    model = User
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                    'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    readonly_fields = ('date_joined', 'last_login')
    form = MyUserChangeForm
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active')
    list_filter = ('is_superuser', 'is_active')
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    ordering = ('email',)
```

I have added these two lines in my `settings.py` files.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",)
```

I have extended this model to a custom profile model. But when I try to create another user I get the following error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'username'")` . Can anybody help me with this?

I am using Django : Django==2.2 with MySql.

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

and test your code.

If everything works then change it.

Comment: Tried using the same : USERNAME_FIELD = 'username' but again received the same error. On the contrary, in my `User` model I had to set username = None and somehow it worked! 
Link : https://www.fomfus.com/articles/how-to-use-email-as-username-for-django-authentication-removing-the-username
Trust me, this is the first time I have encountered this sort of error, inspite of doing all the things correctly

Answer (score 1):

## Add `username` field in your custom user modal

Because error clearly says duplicate entry for key username which means, you have overrides the default user authentication by email id, so every time you create a user `blank` username tries to be created. Still, Django won't allow it's default implementation to be `unique=True`, so you have to override the username attribute also.

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    # add the below one line code
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False, null=True, default=None)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```